# My batch file is not echoing brackets

Tags: batch-file

My batch file is not echoing the left bracket? The code:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set level=1
echo Level Up! (Lv: %level%^)
```

If i use `echo Level Up! (Lv: %level%)` there is no brackets.

Edit:
Put in: `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` Oh and in the code i can not use `endlocal`

Comment: Works fine on my Win7 box, you'll probably need to supply more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo Level Up^^! ^(Lv: %level%^)
```

or even

```
echo Level Up^^! (Lv: %level%)
```

It's the `!` which you need to escape. And the way to escape `!` is with 2 `^`s.